# XCode 4.1 How to add result of External Build System in Products folder of projects tree

Tags: xcode

I have target of type "External Build System" in my XCode project (for packing Google Crome Plugin). How can I make XCode to show reference to built plugin in Products folder of project (like bundles, app, and others)?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do so is to edit project.pbproj in text editor

Answer (score 0):

I found this via an old blog post on [Reordering Xcode's Products Group](https://indiestack.com/2015/02/reordering-xcodes-products-group/) but it works for other modifications too, even as of Xcode 9.3:

1. Rename the "Products" group to something else, e.g. "Products-wip"
2. Now you can edit it! Drag in files as you would to other groups, e.g. for a build script output that writes to "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR" you could reference the file "Relative to Build Products"
3. When done, change the group name back to "Products"

A goofy trick to be sure, but a little bit better than editing the project file by hand!