# How Do I Add The Result of an Xcode Aggregate Target to the "Products" Group?

Tags: xcode, dependencies, product, target

OK. I've looked through the above answers, and I don't think what I want is there. I do see these:

[XCode 4.1 How to add result of External Build System in Products folder of projects tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510106/xcode-4-1-how-to-add-result-of-external-build-system-in-products-folder-of-proje)

[Xcode: Update the project products group with new product name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583662/xcode-update-the-project-products-group-with-new-product-name)

But I don't think they are what I need.

Here's the issue:

I have an aggregate target that [I created to build a framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548483/making-multi-architecture-binaries-in-the-new-ios-8-dynamic-framework-target).

It works a charm. However, I cannot make the resulting framework be considered a target product (manifests as not being able to be dragged into the "Products" group).

I've been poring over the settings, and can't get the result to be considered a "product" of the target.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you manage to get it done?

Comment: No. I never did. It was not a showstopper.